# Join multiple dicts to create new list with value as list of values of original dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm on Python 2.7 and have looked at several solutions here which works if you know how many dictionaries you are merging, but I could have anything between 2 to 5.

I have a loop which generates a dict with the same keys but different values. I want to add the new values to the previous.

Such as:

```
for num in numbers:
    dict = (function which outputs a dictionary)
    [merge with dictionary from previous run of the loop]
```

So if:

```
dict (from loop one) = {'key1': 1,
 'key2': 2,
 'key3': 3}
```

and

```
dict (from loop two) = {'key1': 4,
 'key2': 5,
 'key3': 6}
```

The resultant dict would be:

```
dict = {'key1': [1,4]
 'key2': [2,5],
 'key3': [3,6]}
```

Comment: would the keys among two dicts always be the same?

Comment: Sorry, yes forgot to mention, the keys will always be the same

Answer (score 2):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
In [18]: def gen_dictionaries():
    ...:     yield {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}
    ...:     yield {'key1': 4, 'key2': 5, 'key3': 6}
    ...:

In [19]: from collections import defaultdict

In [20]: final = defaultdict(list)

In [21]: for d in gen_dictionaries():
    ...:     for k, v in d.iteritems():
    ...:         final[k].append(v)
    ...:

In [22]: final
Out[22]: defaultdict(list, {'key1': [1, 4], 'key2': [2, 5], 'key3': [3, 6]})
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this in a generic way is via using `set` to find the union of keys of both the `dict`s and then use a *dictionary comprehension* to get the desired dict as:

```
>>> dict_list = [d1, d2]  # list of all the dictionaries which are to be joined

 # set of the keys present in all the dicts; 
>>> common_keys = set(dict_list[0]).union(*dict_list[1:])

>>> {k: [d[k] for d in dict_list if k in d] for k in common_keys}
{'key3': [3, 6], 'key2': [2, 5], 'key1': [1, 4]}
```

where `d1` and `d2` are:

```
d1 = {'key1': 1,
      'key2': 2,
      'key3': 3}

d2 = {'key1': 4,
      'key2': 5,
      'key3': 6}
```

**Explanation**: Here, `dict_list` is the list of all the `dict` objects you want to combine. Then I am creating the `common_keys` set  of the *keys* in all the dict object. Finally I am creating a new dictionary via using *dictionary comprehension* (with nested *list comprehension* with filter).

---

Based on comment from OP, since all the dicts hold the same keys, we can skip the usage of set. Hence the code could be written as:

```
>>> dict_list = [d1, d2]  

>>> {k: [d[k] for d in dict_list] for k in dict_list[0]}
{'key3': [3, 6], 'key2': [2, 5], 'key1': [1, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'m': 2, 'n':4, 'o':7, 'p':90}
dict2 = {'m': 1, 'n': 3}


dict3 = {}

for key,value in dict1.iteritems():
    if key not in dict3:
        dict3[key] = list()
    dict3[key].append(value)


for key,value in dict2.iteritems():
    if key not in dict3:
        dict3[key] = list()
    dict3[key].append(value)


print(dict3)
```

The output looks like this :

`{'p': [90], 'm': [2, 1], 'o': [7], 'n': [4, 3]}`